# How to iterate over text stored in dataframe to extract in sentences and look for values within the loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have text stored in a Dataframe which contains many sentences. I have written a separate function where I look for certain keywords and values in a sentence and want to be able to store those values in a different column of the same Dataframe. I am having a problem when I iterate over rows of Dataframe to tokenize into each sentence first.

This works when I pass explicit sentences to the function. My problem is when I try to tokenize the text into sentences inside the loop. I get empty result in rf["Nod_size"]. However, "2.9x1.7" and "2.5x1.3" is my expected result.

This is the code I am using

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import nltk
 import re
 from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

 rf = pd.DataFrame([{"Text": "CHEST CA lung. -Increased sizes of nodules in RLL. There is further increased size and solid component of part-solid nodule associated with internal bubbly lucency and pleural tagging at apicoposterior segment of the LUL (SE 3; IM 38-50), now measuring about 2.9x1.7 cm in greatest transaxial dimension (previously size 2.5x1.3 cm in 2015).", "Stage": "T2aN2M0"},
               {"Text": "CHEST CA lung. Post LL lobectomy. As compared to study obtained on 30/10/2018, -Top normal heart size. -Increased sizes of nodules in RLL.", "Stage": "T2aN2M0"}])

 nodule_keywords = ["nodules","nodule"]
 nodule_length_keyword = ["cm","mm", "centimeters", "milimeters"]

 def GetNodule(sentence):
     sentence = re.sub('-', ' ', sentence)
     token_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
     df = pd.DataFrame(token_words)
     df['check_nodkeywords'] = df[0].str.lower().isin(nodule_keywords)
     df['check_nod_len_keywords'] = 
     df[0].str.lower().isin(nodule_length_keyword)
     check = np.any(df['check_nodkeywords']==True)
     check1 =np.any(df['check_nod_len_keywords']==True)
     if ((check==True)&(check1==True)):
          position = np.where(df['check_nod_len_keywords']==True)
          position = position[0]
          nodule_size = df[0].iloc[position-1]
          return nodule_size

 for sub_list in rf['Text']:
     sent = sent_tokenize(str(sub_list))
     for sub_sent_list in sent:
         result_calcified_nod = GetNodule(sub_sent_list)
         rf["Nod_size"] = result_calcified_nod
```

Please Help!! I believe this is a conceptual problem rather than programming. Please help me to solve!

Comment: can you `print(type(sub_list))` inside the for loop and see what is output?

Comment: @Vishal <class 'str'>
              <class 'str'>  This is what I get when I print(type(sub_list)) inside the for loop

Comment: can you try with sent_tokenize(str(sub_list))? and also Do you have any blanks or NaN or None for any specific sub_list? To check this `print(sub_list)` in the for loop.

Comment: I tried with sub_list = None and sublist = np.nan and I got the same error.

Comment: When I insert str as such: sent_tokenize(str(sub_list)), I still have the same error. When I print(sublist), it gives me the text of rows of data as it should be. I am trying with only two rows first and there are no missing data.

Comment: when i ran your whole code, the error is on the line `sentence = re.sub('-', ' ', sentence)` . It is because sentence is list of sentences and re.sub() expects a string only. you can do `print(sent)` after sentence tokenize and it works fine. In short, you are passing list of sentence instead of sentence.

Comment: @Vishal, Considering I am passing a list of sentences. I just added one more for loop inside the previous for loop to send sentence instead of list of sentences. Now, I don't have any error. Yet I get empty results. However, I was supposed to get length as "2.9x1.7" and "2.5x1.3". I have edited the code adding one more for loop. Please help more!

Comment: Why you are doing sentence tokenization? if you do sentence tokenization then in total there are 7 sentences and getNodule returns None for some while it does return 2.9x1.7 and 2.5x1.3 for one of the sentence. However, I am not clear that whether you want to get getNodule on sentence (7 sentences) basis or row(2 only)? Try the below code

`for sub_list in rf['Text']:
    result_calcified_nod = GetNodule(sub_list)
    print (result_calcified_nod)
    rf["Nod_size"] = result_calcified_nod `

Comment: @Vishal I want to get getNodule on row basis. Ok, I may not need sentence tokenization then. However, I used sentence tokenization to look for keywords in one sentence and if keywords found then only look for values in the particular sentence. So, how do I append 2.9x1.7 and 2.5x1.3 in a separate column in rf as rf["Nod_size"]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193095/discussion-between-vishal-and-pari).

Comment: @Vishal I need sentence tokenization. I need to get getNodule on sentence basis and get it stored on respective rows.

Comment: There are 2 rows, but if you do sentence tokenization, then there are total of 7 sentences. How do you want to arrange getNodule? for 2 rows or for 7 sentences?

Comment: @Vishal 3 sentences in the first row. I want to get values based on sentences in each row. Iterate through sentences in each row and add values in the same row accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code should meet your requirement.

```
rf["Nod_size"] = ""
for i,sub_list in zip(range(len(rf)),rf['Text']):
    temp = []
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(sub_list):
        result_calcified_nod = GetNodule(sentence)
        temp.append(result_calcified_nod)
    rf.loc[i]["Nod_size"] = temp
```

Comment: I need sentence tokenization to make sure both keywords I am looking for exists on the same sentence. If I don't do so, I am getting false positive results as it takes any length as nodule length. It will accept as the first keyword is found anywhere in the text.